# Выравнивание по правому краю

Tags: css, bootstrap4

Не получается перенести последний пункт меню (Logout) вправо. Классы `float-right` и `text-right` не помогают. Bootstrap4

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg mb-5">
        <div class="container" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item {% if (app.url == '/admin') %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if (app.url == '/admin/users') %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/users">Users</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if (app.url == '/admin/products') %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                {% if (app.session.user_hash) %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: код в рабочем виде предоставь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся прелесть в том, что нужно вынести последнюю ссылку за список.

```css
nav {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Preview на всю страницу открывайте